# Vue not rendering into html

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue.js, and I am having trouble in rendering vue data to html.

The html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Vue</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
    </div>

    <script src="apps.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the JS file:

```
new VUE({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        name : 'Dhruv'
    }
});
```

Comment: It's `new Vue` not `new VUE`

Comment: Damn....Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comment, it is `new Vue` not `new VUE`.

Also, `data` needs to return an object.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
        name: 'Dhruv',
    };
  }
});
```